# Where to put common CoreGraphics drawing code for view and PDF generation?

Tags: cocoa, drawing, core-graphics

I have a question concerning the placement of CoreGraphics drawing code. I have a C struct which is a representation of my model and I have a custom view class. This custom view class implements a `drawRect` and draws it using CoreGraphics.

I now need the ability to also generate a PDF from this view to export it. It uses the exact same drawing code as used for the view.

My solution right now is to have a separate drawing method in the custom view class and using this method in the `drawRect` method and my method to generate the PDF.

I am not sure if this is a clean solution because the view has a function which has nothing to do with drawing on screen. However using a new custom class as my PDF generator would mean duplicating my drawing code.

Is there a clean way to organize this common drawing code? One could use a helper object and have it as an instance variable but this would make it a bit bloated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Cocoa’s printing architecture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Printing.html) automatically uses the view drawing code when printing, and printing can be used to create a PDF file. This means that you can simply place your custom view drawing code in `-drawRect` and then do something like:

```
NSView *targetView = …;
NSString *pdfFilePath = …;
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
NSPrintOperation *printOp = [NSPrintOperation PDFOperationWithView:targetView
    insideRect:[targetView bounds]
    toData:pdfData];
if ([printOp runOperation]) {
    [pdfData writeToFile:pdfFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can test in `-drawRect:` to see if you're currently drawing to screen or not by using `[NSGraphicsContext currentContextDrawingToScreen]`. If it returns `NO` then you're printing.

Comment: @Rob: Printing or exporting to PDF or EPS. I'm not sure what it returns when the view is rendering into an NSImage or when you've locked focus on the view programmatically (e.g., to use -[NSBitmapImageRep initWithFocusedViewRect:]).

Comment: that is easier than I expected. Thank you. So I can use the code above in my view controller if a button is clicked to export a PDF. So my approach was too low level...